# Drupal 7: Database select query FROM cache_bootstrap brings server down

Tags: caching, bootstrapping

The below query occasionally takes up to 24 sec and consumes the complete server resources.

```
SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized
FROM cache_bootstrap
WHERE cid IN ('variables');
```

I was informed today by my web hoster (I am on a shared server) that above select query brings down the whole node.

I have caching enable (with block caching disabled). JS- and CSS files are aggregated and cached pages are compressed. The site is running ok with no issues.

Any ideas how to track down the problem?

Comment: D7 or D6? Is the cache_bootstrap table InnoDB or MyISAM? If InnoDB what size is innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, mikey! It's D7 (see title of question). It is InnoDB. How can I find/determine the innodb_buffer_pool_size? There is no such table in the database.

Comment: Run this Query:  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the largest tables in the database:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/e4b2c5c3-a72e-42fa-a3f7-8bbb5a83c846/e0387685c6cec210ef7bbafd3871457f

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size 68719476736

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size looks OK as it is 64GB vs the 8MB default... only issue that I see arising is if the MySQL server doesn't have enough ram to support that and is thus swapping. Your table sizes are small as well. What's the output of this query (it's going to have a lot of text) `show engine innodb status`

Comment: Also just to double check the indexes are there, what is the output of the cache_bootstrap query when you add EXPLAIN to it at the start. What version of D7 are you using, 7.26?

Comment: I tried show engine innodb status. But get: #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

Comment: Yes, Drupal 7.26. I ran

`Explain SELECT cid, data, created, expire, serialized FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid IN ('variables');`

here's the result:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/e5c23978-7982-440c-99bd-60f14ae6d854/e34cf8a3ab5022173a16133ac9cd0d8c

Comment: Interestingly the database is gradually growing in size (although no new data is added). Within 6 min it increased by 0.6 MB. Within the last 50 min by 2.4 MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get [memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) properly installed, that will help the most as it will shift queries from the cache tables in the db to your memcache server.

Try these 3 things (in order of importance):
Set the transaction isolation level to Read Committed - https://drupal.org/comment/8437127#comment-8437127 (look in your settings.php for the insertion point; it will be after the $databases variable has been set with the database credentials). This is helpful even if using memcache.

```
$databases['default']['default']['init_commands'] = array(
  'isolation' => "SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'"
);
```

Change your semaphore table to memory - https://drupal.org/comment/8469889#comment-8469889 (use the first code block "Have the name value be a primary key"). Note that this might not work if you are using MySQL 5.0 or lower due to BTREE indexes not working in Memory tables. Also noted that if you are using the memcache version of lock.inc this will not help.

```
ALTER TABLE semaphore ENGINE = MEMORY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD UNIQUE name (name) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX value;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX value (value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX expire;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX expire (expire) USING BTREE;
```

Apply this core patch - https://drupal.org/node/2193149 This will help to reduce database deadlocks from occurring only after the above 2 have been done. If using memcache this core patch will not help as this fixes an issue when using the database as a cache backend.

Comment: I have adjusted my settings.php like this: 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s272/sh/b5104e5c-393a-49aa-bea0-5bdf33d2b746/040c732a03e41628dd187e8527864500

Comment: After changing the semaphore table to memory I got an error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE' at line 1 `

Comment: Put the init_commands part after you set the database user/pass etc. What about if you use the 2nd code block for changing the memory table?

Comment: When I run the 2nd code block I get also an error:
`#1091 - Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists `

Comment: Do the rest of the SQL commands work?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE semaphore ENGINE = MEMORY;` ==> worked!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, value) USING BTREE`==> didn't work
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE' at line 1`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX value;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX value (value) USING BTREE;`==> didn't work `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE' at line 1 `

Comment: The index issue is odd as that should be proper syntax for MySQL 5.0+ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: When I run `ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX value;` the SQL throws: `#1091 - Can't DROP 'value'; check that column/key exists`Not sure what's going on. Database version of the site: ´Database system version 5.0.51a-24+lenny5-log`

Comment: DB still growing. 0.5 MB in the last 30 min. Is this normal?

Comment: The semaphore table needs a PRIMARY index. If that query is failing you need to add it in manually:
http://imgur.com/DV936lR,Bh8dDH8#0 (2 images) Or try running this https://drupal.org/comment/8523869#comment-8523869

Comment: Also noted that the distro your database server is on is quite old http://archive.debian.net/lenny/mysql-client-5.0 and it no longer receives security updates https://wiki.debian.org/DebianLenny

Comment: Can you summarize the links a little?  Maybe extract relevant parts?  I may also do a pass at cleaning up the comments here.

Comment: You can't drop an index twice; that is what the second part is complaining about. Because your MySQL server doesn't like `USING BTREE` for some reason that index was never created. Use the modified syntax in https://drupal.org/comment/8523869#comment-8523869 where USING BTREE is not shown. You might also have to remove the DROP  queries depending on if MySQL complains about it.

Comment: MPD, I have cleaned up my comments. Only the relevant ones remain.

Comment: I ran the commands in #comment-8523869 but again to no avail:
`#1091 - Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists`

I will try to do it manually.

Comment: I ran the commands in the second table of #comment-8523869 one by one. Starting from the bottom up. Now all commands worked. Seems I got this patch in. Thanks Mikey!

I just looked at the database. In the last 8 hr it grew from 17 MB to 42 MB.

Comment: When I run cron the size of the DB doesn't change. When I clear the cache in the backend, the size goes down from 42 MB to 16.8 MB again.

Comment: No problems with cache_bootstrap anymore. The only issue is with cache_metatags but other than that the above steps seem to have worked.

Comment: metatags does have some performance issues. I have a patch here that fixes one aspect of it: https://drupal.org/node/2183203#comment-8425569