# DrupalDatabaseCache::set Devel Module

Tags: caching, debugging

I seem to be getting slow speeds with 
DrupalDatabaseCache::set and DrupalDatabaseCache::getMultiple

i am using drupal 7 and am on a Virtual Private Server on Dreamhost which is running Fast CGI and xchache

Any tips on how to get these requests (40+ milliseconds) down under 5mills?

there are some other querries that are above 5 milliseconds
user_roles, menu_get_item, menu_item_visibility_load etc..

any tips for overall improvement in the time querries take to load?

Answer (score 1):

1. Best Option: Use a non DB cache backend like [Memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache)
2. Next Best: Use a MySQL derivative that [supports blob columns in a memory table](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/09/06/dynamic-row-format-for-memory-tables/) and convert all cache tables to be of the type memory. Be sure to [rebuild the indexes as BTREE's instead of HASH](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/02/01/performance-gotcha-of-mysql-memory-tables/) after converting to MEMORY. More details on this can be seen in this presentation: http://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/drupal-and-mysql-performance-percona-live-mysql-webinar
3. Still good: Follow the directions here: [Drupal 7: Database select query FROM cache_bootstrap brings server down](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104880/drupal-7-database-select-query-from-cache-bootstrap-brings-server-down/104886#104886)

Note that all 3 of the above options are independent from each other; so you can do all 3. Also noted that the answer in #3, his database server was configured reasonably well; you might need to [tune InnoDB](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/) in order to get better performance out of your's.

EDIT:
Also checkout my guide on tuning D7 https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1AgnurTWsWdMAFjfFmSU7mk2zfJu8jG_KmVdZ7-o6Pok/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Thanks for the very straight forward list! followup question: Will any of the above not work well with Drupal Commerce modules (dynamic content like shopping cart and checkout)?

Comment: I believe these all should work with it.