# Install APC and Memcache and their extensions

Tags: caching

I am building a drupal 7 site.
My site is currently hosted on the bluehost - shared hosting.

When I tried to install [APC module](https://drupal.org/project/apc) I got the following error: "The APC module needs the apc extension see: http://www.php.net/apc. (Currently using APC Not available)"

I have no idea how to install the extension (even after I read not-so-clear guides).

I spoke with the support of bluehost, and they told my I can't install the APC extension on shared hosting.

I also tried to install the [Memcache Module](https://drupal.org/project/memcache).
I also got here the following error: "(Currently using Extensions not available Either the memcache or memcached extensions must be installed in order to use memcache integration.)
You must enable the PECL memcached or memcache extension to use memcache.inc."

I really can't use the APC module?
Can someone please help me install the APC module & extensions?

What about the Memcache Module?
How can I install & enable the PECL?

Comment: Shared hosting usually doesn't have APC installed & if they don't want to install it you'll need to find a new shared host that supports APC (I don't know if any exist) or switch to a virtual private server (VPS) so you can install it your self. Long story short you'll have to pay more most likely.

Comment: @mikeytown2 thanks for your answer. What about the Memcache module?

Comment: The memcache module needs the memcached or memcache PHP extension, Again that's not something you can install on a shared hosting. It also needs a memcached server. And again, that's nod something shared hosting provider usually provide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installing server-side PHP modules

Answer (score 1):

If your stuck with shared hosting there are a couple of options to make Drupal faster.

Use some form of a file cache for the page cache. Boost & filecache's filecache_fast_pagecache option will serve cached pages a lot quicker than core does. For the other cache tables filecache or Drupal's core database cache might be quicker; you'll have to test to see what one works better on your shared hosting.
https://drupal.org/project/boost
https://drupal.org/project/filecache

Optimize your database. This is a post of things that can be done on the drupal side; there is a lot more that can be done if you can change the mysql side.
[Drupal 7: Database select query FROM cache_bootstrap brings server down](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104880/drupal-7-database-select-query-from-cache-bootstrap-brings-server-down/104886#104886)